# What does the Horn do?

Tags: you-must-build-a-boat

I have collected a Horn, which appears to get charged up in the top right of the screen while running in the match-three section.

Every so often it gets 'used' and lots of monsters seem to whizz past my characters

Can anyone explain:-

1) How the charge bar is filed?
2) What is actually happening when it gets used
3) Can I use it on demand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has just been posted by the games author on the subject of the Hammerhorn.

http://www.pockettactics.com/features/luca-redwood-reveals-dark-secrets-of-ymbabs-hammerhorn/

Answer (score 3):

It slowly fills up while you are running (or matching tiles?). Once the bar is full, it's some kind of life saver: Whenever you are about to get defeated by a monster, the horn is triggered and all you captured monsters come to help you. They deal a lot of damage to all monsters on screen. It can't prevent you from failing to open up a chest, but when you run again afterwards, the bar is still completely filled. You can't trigger it manually.

One of the last shield upgrades has a passive ability to fill it up faster.

I actually never paid a lot of attention to it. You need to quickly clear your board to get more swords/staffs afterwards, or the next monster will probably still end your run. But it's really helpful if you are lucky enough to have a full bar when a hard boss appears.

Comment: I've just had the Horn trigger when my character was about halfway along the screen, so not in danger of 'Winning' by being pushed off the left hand edge